# jinja NativeEnvironment casts an int string to a literal int

Tags: python, jinja2

This surprised me:

```
import jinja2.nativetypes

env = jinja2.nativetypes.NativeEnvironment()
result = env.from_string('{{ x }}')
value = result.render(x='2')
print(type(value))
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
```

Looking over the native parser code it seems like it takes string nodes and runs them through `ast.parse()` and then treats it like a literal.

So `ast.parse` takes the string whose value is 2 and parses it as an integer through the ast parser.  (if it parsed it from `repr('2')` it would actually work right...)

I've asked and this is not a bug, so I'm looking for a workaround.  This is what I currently have, but I am unsure whether this is the best way to address this, especially since I don't understand what problem the ast.parse/parse_literal is trying to solve in the original (Is it trying to solve `{{ "a+1" }}` ??)

```
def _concat(values: t.Iterable[t.Any]) -> t.Optional[t.Any]:                              
    # based on native_concat from https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/main/src/jinja2/nativetypes.py
    head = list(islice(values, 2))                                                        
    if not head:                                                                          
        return None                                                                       
                                                                                          
    if len(head) == 1:                                                                    
        raw = head[0]                                                                     
        # Removed this line.  Always return raw when single node.                  
        # if not isinstance(raw, str):                                                    
        return raw                                                                        
                                                                                          
    # Removed this else since we always return raw above.                                 
    # else:                                                                               
    if isinstance(values, GeneratorType):                                                 
        values = chain(head, values)    
                                              
    raw = "".join([str(v) for v in values])                                               
                                                                                          
    try:                                                                                  
        return literal_eval(                                                              
            # In Python 3.10+ ast.literal_eval removes leading spaces/tabs                
            # from the given string. For backwards compatibility we need to               
            # parse the string ourselves without removing leading spaces/tabs.            
            parse(raw, mode="eval")                                                       
        )                                                                                 
    except (ValueError, SyntaxError, MemoryError):                                        
        return raw                                                                        
                                                                                          
                                                                                          
class FixedNativeEnvironment(jinja2.nativetypes.NativeEnvironment):                       
    # Fix for https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/1904                                
    concat = staticmethod(_concat)  # type: ignore                                        
                                                                                          
                                                                                          
class FixedNativeTemplate(jinja2.nativetypes.NativeTemplate):                             
    environment_class = FixedNativeEnvironment
```

Any better suggestions that what I have above?  What use cases do I break above?

Comment: Then why does `value = result.render(x=[1,2,3,4])` work?   Am I supposed to pass every value in as repr([1,2,3,4]) ?   I think not: `env.from_string('{{ x[0] }}').render(x=repr([1,2,3]) -> "["` I don't want to work with strings.  I want what I pass in to be returned consistently be the type I passed in.

Comment: (Comment above was in response to a now deleted comment about I should be passing `x="'2'"`)

Another example of why that makes no sense:  `env.from_string('{{ x + "a" }}').render(x="'2'") -> "'2'a"`

`